# Test against private variable values

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

All right, do not get angry now, I know there are several questions about this topic, but I still have some doubts.

I think I totally agree about not testing private functions, I find it reasonable, but how can I test public methods that set private variables?

Let's say that the constructor set some private variables and I want to test that those variable are correctly set after the constructor is called. Is it a valid test? How should I check the value of the private variables without adding public getters?

I add a not real scenario example to try to be clearer:

```
public class ClassToTest
{
   private bool _isOn;

   public void SwitchOn() { _isOn = true; }
   public void SwitchOff(){ _isOn = false; }

   public void update()
   {
      if (_isOn)
        DoSomething();
   }

   private void DoSomething()
   {
     //this could also execute a function of an external dependency. But still the dependency could not have a public function to test if the behavior actually ran.
   }
}
```

how can I test that SwitchOn and SwitchOff work properly if I cannot test against the _isOn value? (this is an example, it implies that I will not write a public getter and the functions do not return a value because they do not need to)

Comment: Do you need to check their values? Can you not be sure of their values by the way they are used in other methods?

Comment: Your problem most likely lies elsewhere. You shouldn't test private parts of class, as those are implementation details irrelevant to their consumers. Can you provide more context/code sample representing problem? Otherwise you might get too general answers.

Comment: (Tip: Never use default int. use 'private int _isOn;'. Or 'private bool _isOn;'.)

Comment: (Tip: Never use a _underbar in a C language. The actual rule is "no _CapitalLetter", but just don't use them anyway. Try isOn_, for a little marker that you are private.)

Comment: Now what's the program behavior if the switch is on? In this case, you don't need to test something that does nothing! C-;

Comment: sorry it was meant to be a bool. It is c# and I like _convention

Comment: @Phlip this is a simple example; there could be another function in the same class that relies on the isOn value...but I think I see your point

Comment: Answered below where I can write linefeeds & such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests should use the Assemble/Activate/Assert pattern:

```
test switch on {
  x = new ClassToTest();
  x.SwitchOn();   //  <--  Assemble an on switch
  EmptyMailQueue();   // <-- Assemble nothing in the Q

  PossiblySendUserEmail();  // <-- Activate the feature

  assert(mailQueue.count() == 1);
  }

test switch on {
  x = new ClassToTest();
  x.SwitchOff();
  EmptyMailQueue();

  PossiblySendUserEmail();

  assert(mailQueue.count() == 0); // <-- Assert switch is off so no mails sent
  }
```

You assert the actual reason you have a switch. Testing the switch itself breaks the rule "Don't TDD getters and setters".

Comment: ah, I was taking as example this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5019/Advanced-Unit-Testing-Part-I-Overview where setters are actually tested

Comment: anwyay beside the setters I figured out what you wrote on my own as well, but you still assume that something is public (count)...I could write another example where the ClassToTest receives a dependency that has a function that runs according the isOn value. The same dependency could not have a public function to test that the function actually ran though.

Comment: That codeproject article goes long on architecture. The author carefully excuses he does not address "test-first". His primary goal is showing how completed NUnit test cases fit into completed architectures.

Comment: look at my extended example please and thank you for the help

Comment: Here's Clifton's writeup on TDD, but it has no examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10105/Writing-Your-First-Unit-Test

Comment: although I am not using TDD, I will check the principles.

Comment: Use TDD, because then your code will be decoupled as it's written. Adding unit tests to code that's already written is much slower!

Comment: Next, to get out of an awkward situation, just throw in a Mock Object. It will confirm that a correct internal private secret method got called.

Comment: the problem is that we have started to use Unit Test too late, most of the project is done already and most of the colleagues, included me, do not have experience with Unit Testing.

Comment: I started this thread doing anything to avoid saying "throw a Mock Object at it". If you indeed have "legacy" code (meaning "already written and without tests"), then throw a Mock Object at it! C-;

Answer (score -1):

You need to test private members, because they might have bugs in them.

"Private" is not a magic barrier, it's simply a convention advising production-code clients not to call that member directly.

Prepending all such member with an _underbar would be just as useful as C++ protecting such methods with hardware.

Your car engine has plugs inside that should not be used while driving, only when a mechanic tests things. Software should be the same. Test your private members, and disable private if you need to.

However...

---

The point of an object is to expose behavior. If your private variable is set correctly, then your object should behave correctly. Your tests should request this behavior.

Look up "Test-Driven Development" (and start using it *yesterday*), and look up "Intentional Programming". Your test cases should start by requesting that behavior, and should not worry about implementation details. If you upgrade an object to use different internals, you don't need too many tests breaking for no reason.

(Go not to elves, or software methodologists, for advice, for they will say both Yes and No!;)